# PHP: Editing a file using a dynamic filename

Tags: php, edit

I have a PHP script that I am trying to edit some text files that have a dynamic file name.  I think I am about 90% there, but am having an issue where the resulting output filename is incorrect.

The files in question I am trying to edit are for VoIP phones nad have a ormat of MAC.cfg, where MAC is the MAC address of the phone in question.

I have an HTML page that is just a very simple form where the MAC address is entered, and the form calls a PHP script that using that MAC address and brings up the contents of the appropriate MAC.cfg file.  When I edit what I want to edit, however, the resulting filename becomes MAC.cfg.cfg (i.e., it adds an extra ".cfg" to it), and I do not know why.

The code for the page where the MAC address of the phone gets entered is:

```
<form method="post" action="edit-imaccfg.php">
<input type="text" name="macaddress" value="">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

and the contents of 'edit-imaccfg.php' is this:

```
<?php
// set file to read
$filename = $_POST['macaddress'].=".cfg";

$newdata = $_POST['newd'];

if ($newdata != '') {

// open file
$fw = fopen($filename, 'w') or die('Could not open file!');
// write to file
// added stripslashes to $newdata
$fb = fwrite($fw,stripslashes($newdata)) or die('Could not write to file');
// close file
fclose($fw);
}

// open file
$fh = fopen($filename, "r") or die("Could not open file!");
// read file contents
$data = fread($fh, filesize($filename)) or die("Could not read file!");
// close file
fclose($fh);
// print file contents
?>

<html>
<body>
<form action="<?= $_SERVER[php_self] ?>" method="POST" >
<textarea name="newd" cols="100%" rows="100"> <?= $data ?> </textarea>
<input type="hidden" name="macaddress" value="<?= $_POST['macaddress'] ?>" />
<input type="submit" value="Change">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't know what, in the above code, is adding the extra '.cfg' to the outputted filename, rather than overwriting the intended MAC.CFG file.

Your insight is greatly appreciated  Thanks! :-)

Comment: It is because you are appending to the post variable and then using it in the form: `$filename = $_POST['macaddress'].=".cfg";`  Take out the second `=`  >> `$filename = $_POST['macaddress'].".cfg";`  or better yet: `$filename = "{$_POST["macaddress"]}.cfg";`

Comment: That was it.  Thanks!  I went with the "or better yet" option :-)